# How to see what INKSCAPE command is getting executed when am performing an action in the GUI

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, inkscape

Am a programmer trying to implement a certain action on a SVG image using INKSCAPE Command Line. I tried using the **`inkscape --verb-list`** and **`inkscape --action-list`** commands and yet found no command satisfying my needs. However I know how to perform the required action using the **INKSCAPE GUI**. So, is there a way I can see all the equivalent commands for everything I do in the GUI. If yes, please enlighten.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think that exists. The list of actions is far from being complete.